# Plotly chart is not displayed in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, plotly

How can I display interactive plotly graphs in Pycharm? I run the following code:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

data = [go.Bar(
    x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y=[20, 14, 23]
)]

py.iplot(data, filename="barplot")
```

The result in PyCharm is a blank field:
[image: Plotly result in Pycharm]

In Jupyter Notebook this code gives a (proper) interactive chart as the result.

**Update:**
Answers from [Embed Plotly HTML in PyCharm IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39448549/embed-plotly-html-in-pycharm-ide) don't work for me. When I use the `plot()` function (instead of the `iplot()`) it exports the chart into separate file and open a browser in a new window. The output in notebook is the filename of the generated chart. I want to include the chart into notebook and use it interactively, like in Jupyter Notebook. That answers are only about exporting the chart into separate html file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed Plotly HTML in PyCharm IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39448549/embed-plotly-html-in-pycharm-ide)

Comment: @MaximilianPeters that question is different- I don't want to export the chart into separate file, I want to include it into notebook and use it interactively, like in Jupyter Notebook. That question (and answer) is about exporting the chart into separate html file.

Comment: I guess the issue is discussed here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14534

Comment: Issue PY-1453 is about interactive widgets, is that the way plotly creates interactive charts? Is the lack of support for these widgets in PyCharm the reason plotly can't be displayed in the PyCharm SciView? I would like an answer to address plotly in PyCharm SciView, not just notebooks.

Comment: @wind What Pycharm version are you running?

Comment: @vestland as I remember it was 2018.1

Comment: similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211392/how-can-i-see-plotly-graphs-in-pycharm

Answer (score 27):

jayBana's answer is correct, but if you want to keep using .py scripts in PyCharm, you can simply set default renderer to 'browser' to get interactive plotly graphs:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "browser"
```

as described here: https://plot.ly/python/renderers/

Comment: This is excellent advice! Plotly is than working from normal Python files.

Answer (score 6):

I hope someone proves me wrong, but what you are trying to accomplish does in fact seem to not be possible at the moment. I was hoping that your problem was perhaps limited to the community editions of PyCharm. The [Scientific](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html) mode of PyCharm is stated to have

> [...] an outstanding set of features [...]

So, I was pretty sure that upgrading to the [Professional Edition Version 2019.1.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) would provide a version not lacking in *any* form of Jupyter Notebook support. Alas, It seems I was wrong. I have tried with various other plotly approaches, but found none that makes it possible to fire up an interactive plotly figure.

**As close to any proof that I can provide:**

[image]

**Version confirmation:**

[image]

---

Here's a test run from a Jupyter Notebook not in PyCharm with your snippet:

**Plot:**

[image]

---

Also, as suggested in the comments, replacing `iplot` with `plot` in `plotly.offline.plot(plot(data), filename='file.html')` *will* open a web browser and display your plot too.

Comment: If I may,  the proper syntax is  `py.plot(data, filename='file.html')` (inline with @wind code) or `plotly.offline.plot(data, filename='file.html')` with `import plotly` first. Otherwise you end up with error `TypeError: plot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'figure_or_data'`

Answer (score 6):

With the recently released major version of Plotly 4.0, the steps below work for me with PyCharm 2019.2 on macOs Mojave using iPython notebooks from within PyCharm.

I believe that this should work on other operating systems as well with other recent versions of PyCharm supporting Jupyter notebooks.

I am using `conda` for package and environment management but this should work with other tools as well e.g. pip or pipenv (given that orca is installed standalone)

**Here are my steps:**

Create and activate conda environment:

- `$ conda create -n pycharm-plotly python`
- `$ conda activate pycharm-plotly`

Install Plotly 4.0 and its dependencies as per the [plotly.py's GitHub README for Jupyter Notebook Support](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py#jupyter-notebook-support)

- `$ conda install -c plotly plotly==4.0.0`
- `$ conda install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.5"`

In addition, I found that "Plotly Orca" is required for this to work:

- `$ conda install -c plotly plotly-orca psutil requests`

Please note that the above works with both "Configured Server" and "Managed Server" from within PyCharm for `.ipynb` file extensions using the following sample code:

```py
#%%
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default = 'png'

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure Displayed with fig.show()"
)
fig.show();
```

[image]

**Additional Notes:**

- I believe that Plotly's plot rendering doesn't work with "plain" Python files in PyCharm's Scientific mode the same way as it works for Matplotlib or Seaborn.

Answer (score 5):

If you would just simply want to show the plot without any hassle here is how I display to browser for only specific plots.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# Plot histogram based on rolling 2 dice
dice_1 = np.random.randint(1,7,5000)
dice_2 = np.random.randint(1,7,5000)
dice_sum = dice_1 + dice_2
# bins represent the number of bars to make
fig = px.histogram(dice_sum, nbins=11, labels={'value':'Dice Roll'},
             title='5000 Dice Roll Histogram', marginal='violin',
            color_discrete_sequence=['green'])

fig.show(renderer="browser")
```

[image]

**NOTE** the `renderer="browser"` you can of course change it to other outputs. Here is a list of them [docs](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/)

Comment: This doens't work for me, I get "this site cannot be reached, refused to connect"

Answer (score 0):

As of `plotly` version 4, all you need to do is call `.show()` on any `go.Figure`:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure( go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,3,2] ) )
fig.show()
```

Comment: this doesn't work, at least without any further installations

Comment: this works with PyCharm Community 2023.3.4. I am from Java, now exploring python, so forgive my ignorance, but when comparing between Jupyter notebook and Pycharm, I noticed that to print something, like a pandas dataframe, you just need to write its name in Jupyter, (for instance, df), but in PyCharm you need print(df). Same for graphs, you need to add this extra line of code, fig.show(). So this answer is valid...