# How to see plotly graphs in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, plotly

I see the following renderers are available:

```
Default renderer: 'browser'
    Available renderers:
        ['plotly_mimetype', 'jupyterlab', 'nteract', 'vscode',
         'notebook', 'notebook_connected', 'kaggle', 'azure', 'colab',
         'json', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'svg', 'pdf', 'browser',
         'firefox', 'chrome', 'chromium', 'iframe', 'iframe_connected',
         'sphinx_gallery']
```

but I don't see how I can get Pycharm to show the output, in the IDE, like when I do graphs with Matplotlib.

how can this be done?

---

Edit:

This is the code I use, sample from plotly:

```
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="test"
)
fig.show()
```

This will open a browser tab to show the graph while run in the Pycharm debugger.

---

Edit2:

I see a similar question, from a year ago, with no solution:

[Plotly chart is not displayed in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250010/plotly-chart-is-not-displayed-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps:

- right click and select "*Run file in python console*"
- after that browser will be opened with graph output

See screenshot below:

[image]

[Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDELu.png)

Answer (score 3):

With Plotly.py version 4, it should be as simple as calling `fig.show()` with the `svg` renderer

[image]

Comment: for me, it opens a page in the browser, at address http://127.0.0.1:55836/, and displays the graph, even though it's run from pycharm's debugger

Comment: I noticed your project is in a jupyter notebook. I have a project just set as a python script. Maybe PyCharm handles things differently based on the type of project set up at the beginning

Comment: Sorry, yes, and the renderer in the screenshot is set to SVG

Comment: ok, so you need to run orca locally to serve the pictures then

Comment: Yeah but it’s really easy, just install it and it takes care of itself, no need to turn it on/off manually etc.

Comment: I just did, but now the debugger returns this: {'image/svg+xml': '<svg class="main-svg" ....  essentially the whole svg, but pycharm doesn't display it, it's just output in the console. if I don't take the svg renderer, but leave the default, then it still goes to the browser. I wonder if it's not linked to project types (jupyter vs. plain python) where the debugger would interpret the output differently

Comment: Can you display any type of chart in the debugger eg matplotlib charts? I wouldn’t be surprised if the debugger just didn’t handle this sort of thing at all

Comment: yes, with matplotlibs, no problem at all. I'm upgraded to PyCharm 2019.2 to see if i it would work, but no, same thing. I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting it because I don't know how PyCharm and matplotlib communicate to start with

Comment: Maybe try the `png` renderer in that case?

Comment: the debugger outputs the png in the console: {'image/png': 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAArwAAAHC...
Is the normal pycharm behavior to display the output of a program based on its mime type?

Comment: Hmm ok then I’m out of ideas :)

Comment: It looks like your best bet from the debugger is to stay with the default `browser` renderer today, which opens up a new window but still does all rendering locally on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

The steps below work for me with PyCharm 2019.2 on macOs Mojave using iPython notebooks from within PyCharm.

I believe that this should work on other operating systems as well with other recent versions of PyCharm supporting Jupyter notebooks as well.

I am using `conda` for package and environment management but this should work with other tools as well e.g. pip or pipenv (given that orca is installed standalone)

**Here are my steps:**

Create and activate conda environment:

- `$ conda create -n pycharm-plotly python`
- `$ conda activate pycharm-plotly`

Install Plotly 4.0 and its dependencies as per the [plotly.py's GitHub README for Jupyter Notebook Support](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py#jupyter-notebook-support)

- `$ conda install -c plotly plotly==4.0.0`
- `$ conda install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.5"`

In addition, I found that "Plotly Orca" is required for this to work:

- `$ conda install -c plotly plotly-orca psutil requests`

Please note that the above works with both "Configured Server" and "Managed Server" from within PyCharm for `.ipynb` file extensions using the following sample code:

```py
#%%
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default = 'png'

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure Displayed with fig.show()"
)
fig.show();
```

[image]

**Additional Notes:**

- I believe that Plotly's plot rendering doesn't work with "plain" Python files in PyCharm's Scientific mode the same way as it works for Matplotlib or Seaborn.

Comment: While this does work, a big advantage of plotly is the interactiveness. This will only display the graphs as images. Better than no graph though.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after hours you need to follow the easy use library from plotly

https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/

My code is working now in the webrowser without any problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4), columns='A B C D'.split())
print(df.head())
fig = px.line(df)
fig.show()
```