# Plotly express not showing plots in PyCharm SciView

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, plotly

I'm trying to render a Plotly graph in PyCharm's SciView-Plots panel (using PyCharm Professional 2020.3).

A simplified version of what I'm running is:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default = 'png'

fig = px.scatter(data)
fig.show()
```

This code runs, but does not show a plot. Instead I see a printout in the console that looks like:

```
{'image/png': 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh<cropped for brevity...>'}
```

I was working on following this article, but the solutions there don't seem to work: [how can I see plotly graphs in pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211392/how-can-i-see-plotly-graphs-in-pycharm)

Comment: plt.figure()
fig = px.scatter(data)
plt.show()

Give this a try? I sometimes had issues with PyCharm when using fig.show(), not plt.show()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sciview will support `matplotlib.pyplot.show`, therefore you can export to png, then display the png using `matplotlib.pyplot.show`

```
import io
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

pio.renderers.default = 'png'


def plot(fig):
    img_bytes = fig.to_image(format="png")
    fp = io.BytesIO(img_bytes)
    with fp:
        i = mpimg.imread(fp, format='png')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(i, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.show()


x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
fig = px.scatter(x, y)
plot(fig)
```

works with Pycharm professional 2019.3

Comment: You need to win a hackathon for wacky solutions like that. :)