# Plotly not displaying figure on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, plotly, visualization

I'm trying to run `Plotly` on `PyCharm`. Following code does not work:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure Displayed with fig.show()"
)

fig.show()
```

But this works on my colleague's laptop. When he runs the code, the figure is displayed on a browser with the address `127.0.0.1:some_port`

Why can he run and I can't? Is it possible to run `Plotly` figures without using offline mode (I can run the code using `plot` but I prefer the other way around as all tutorials use the online mode)

Comment: Can you expand on "does not work"? Are you seeing an error? What kind of window are you running this code in? In a console or a notebook or...? Also, is your colleague also using PyCharm?

Comment: @nicolaskruchten I run this code in PyCharm. The code runs, there is no error but the figure does not appear in browser.

Comment: Could you try this? I hope the question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250010/plotly-chart-is-not-displayed-in-pycharm