# Plotly not showing graphs in pycharm

Tags: python, plotly, data-science, iplots

Iplot is not showing any output in pycharm and neither does it give any error[Here is the code I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OvI7.png)

Comment: Please include the code in your post rather than linking to a picture of the code

Comment: try po.plot instead of po.iplot

Comment: @Yaman Aggarwal Have you seen [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250010/plotly-chart-is-not-displayed-in-pycharm/56224210#56224210)

Comment: @vestland Yes I tried even this it still doesn't work